# How to connect a network printer over Android?

Tags: android, networking, printing

I want to code an Android app, which will connect to a network printer with a specific IP address, and then make a printing.

For printing I know that I need to write my own Postscript for specific files types, and connecting to a network is not a problem over WIFI.

How to connect to the network printer?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 20):

Any device connected to a network will communicate via their IP and Ports / sockets. The simplest way to connect via telnet or socket and write the data to their socket buffers.

```
try 
    {
    Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.1.222", 9100);
    PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        oStream.println("HI,test from Android Device");
        oStream.println("\n\n\n");
        oStream.close();
        sock.close(); 
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: how to get the port ?

Comment: it worked for me, i want to print a pdf file, could you help me there

Comment: I have some different Url like Ip, Port like 192.168.100.101:9090/printer/print                How to use this Url for Print ?

Comment: @luis can you tell me which printer you have used?

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar Which printer you have used?

Comment: @user3219477 I think it was an HP printer. The important thing for me was that the printer supported PCL (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language)

Comment: Works great! But how can I print in xml format? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [lpdspooler](http://lpdspooler.sourceforge.net/), that is, if the printer supports LPR/LPD. If you can give some more details about the environment (printer, etc), I might be able to give more information.

Comment: Test printer is EPSON TM-T88III (Ethernet). I need to check if it supports LPR/LDP.

Comment: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas1aeb8bc2140732fb2862569c10078efbb&wv=1

It shows that printer supports LPR.

Comment: I looked into lpdspooler again, and it doesn't look like exactly what you want, but I see your printer does support LPR and RAW. I found [this link](http://code.google.com/p/jprinterface/source/browse/trunk/src/sos/net/print/LPR.java?r=2) to the source for a project which sends a job to a printer through LPR in java; I believe it will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks Gregory, let me try it. I will inform you about the results. Now at least i have something to start with.

Comment: Did you figure out something?

Comment: Hi, i tried the link which Gregory provided, it worked as java application without any problem. But whenever i tried the same idea and code in Android, i ended up SocketTimeOut error while writing data file. I tried wakelock and increasing the amount of timeout but it didnt help, i will check with wireshark to see what is wrong, still working on it. It is early to say it but i think it can happen because of permission problems there is nothing i can think of for now, any help is appriciated.

Comment: Hi guys, Even I am looking for print sdks, is this code is beneficial in android, explain how?

Answer (score 1):

Just Add This Code After oncreate Method

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Star has an Android SDK which has port discovery. It'll find any of their wifi receipt printers on your network. http://starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PrintManager: https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs

```
  private void doPrint() {
    // Get a PrintManager instance
    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    // Set job name, which will be displayed in the print queue
    String jobName = getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

    // Start a print job, passing in a PrintDocumentAdapter implementation
    // to handle the generation of a print document
    printManager.print(jobName, new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(getActivity()),
            null); //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution. I used Epson TM series. I think the port is 9100 for default.
In Manifest add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in the activity use a Thread otherwise u you can the android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               try  {
                  Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.1.168", 9100);
                  PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                  oStream.println("Hi, test from Android Device");
                  oStream.println("\n");
                  oStream.close();
                  sock.close();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e)
                  {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  catch (IOException e)
                  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                    }});
```

If not enough, add in manifest these:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, you cant connect any devices directly as you will need the driver installed. there are 3rd party apps like [Google Cloud](http://www.androidsim.net/2011/12/how-to-43-setup-google-cloud-print-for.html) print that works seamlessly with Android though.

Comment: **No**, this is the microsoft windows' ed way. In fact, many **good quality** devices, like printers, modems, sound cards, etc, support standard communication protocols, so you can connect **without any drivers installed**. See the accepted answer for example.