# Android ESC/POS Printing Over WiFi

Tags: android, printing, wifi

I want to write an Android app which will do following in steps and I want you to help me find right APIs for them to speed up the process. The printer I am going to use supports ESC/POS protocols.

1. Find all printers nearby using WiFi.
2. It will select one printer may be first one.
3. It will send a text document to printer for printing and will see if it was printed successfully.

I found some APIs like **[this](http://www.cm-soft.com/AndroidPrinterSDK.htm)**. I believe my problem is similar to **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301132/how-to-connect-a-network-printer-over-android)**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have been looking into this for a long time.  There are almost no APIs out there, much less good APIs.  The only one I have gotten to work so far is the [Epson Android SDK](http://pos.epson.com/mobilesdks/index.htm).

This supports a number of wifi and bluetooth epson printers.  With just a few lines of code, you can find the IP address of the printer you want to print with, and then add lines to the document to print.  They also have a good sample app that has every kind of operation you might want to do.

You can manually write ESC commands, but it is very complecated.  That is why things like [JavaPos](http://www.javapos.com/) were developed, to attempt to abstract these details away.  However, here is an Epson manual for [ESC commands](http://www.delfi.com/SupportDL/Epson/Manuals/TM-T88IV/Programming%20manual%20APG_1005_receipt.pdf)

UPDATE:
the epson android sdk link is out of date.  Here is an [up-to-date link](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=4747&scat=50&pcat=52)

Comment: Did you try working on non-Epson POS printer with this SDK ?