# can we connect to thermal receipt printer via bluetooth in react native

Tags: android, printing, react-native

Is it possible to connect to thermal receipt printer via Bluetooth in react native? If yes the how to connect receipt printer via Bluetooth in react native?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data to bluetooth printer vai android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796422/how-to-send-data-to-bluetooth-printer-vai-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. For Bluetooth you need to use a third-party module, like [react-native-ble](https://github.com/jacobrosenthal/react-native-ble) or [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager).