# Accessing Printer through android

Tags: android

I have an IP address of my my printer on the network.
I want to send print command on that printer. What shoul i do for this..   Any one help me fo this. Thanks

Comment: Here's an easy way to print text to a network printer from Android: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13584763/1172181

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple as HttpConnection & writing DataOutputStream,
First of all you need to make Serial Connection with that IP address. After making Connection you need to make DataOutputStream for writing files/words , these will goes to printer & will print it. I did same for Bluetooth Printer previously.

Comment: At Present , i do not have it. but I will try to look for it in my folder, if found then surely give you.

Comment: @Android about which file you discussed here?

Comment: @Android i have same problem so please give me the source code to print text from my app to printer

Comment: Here'a an easy and straight forward implementation for printing text: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13584763/1172181